# Insert 3 distinct rings into 2 fingers and insert 2 fingers into 3 distinct rings.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Here are the problems I am unable to grasp.

A- **Insert $3$ distinct rings into $2$ fingers**.

and
B- **insert $2$ fingers into $3$ distinct rings**.

Both questions seem similar but **1st one has $2×2×2=8$ ways** from multiplication principle and **2nd one has $3×3= 9$ ways** from multiplication principle.

When I try to figure out number of ways by manual counting I get only 6 ways for both questions

For question (A) I get-$(r1,f1),(r1,f2), (R2,f1), (R2,f2), (r3,f1), (r3,f2)$

For question (B) I get- $(f1,r1),(f1,R2), (f1,r3), (f2,r1), (f2,R2) , (f2,r3)$.

Why my answers are different i.e. only 6 ways and not 8 or 9 ways? Can any one provide correct manual counting?

Comment: Are you asking how many ways three distinct rings can be placed on two fingers?

Comment: The multiplication principle gives the right answers. The two questions are similar, but not identical. The first question does not permit having a single ring be on two different fingers at the same time; the second question permits two different fingers  to be inserted into the same ring at the same time. B doesn't permit a single finger to be placed into more than one ring at a time; A does.

Comment: Whatever the parts a and b are, are the fingers specified? Can I count putting rings on my right ring and index fingers separately from putting rings on my left pinky and middle fingers?

Comment: With either question, is it permitted to put all three rings on just one finger? Or must each of the two fingers have at least one ring in the end?

Comment: Assume All three rings can be wore on index finger or mid finger.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig I think that question A means the same as you have asked. Insert 3 rings on 2fingers(let say index and mid finger)= how many ways 3rings can be wore on 2 fingers. If there is any difference in the 2 meanings will the answer also differ?

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson thank you. That is really helpful.

Comment: Reworded & asked again, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503343/difference-in-questions-and-their-outcomes-for-selecting-2-pants-and-3-shirts

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am not doing it for rewards. I post doubts to get some insight from more knowledgble persons than me. You yourself and many others have been much helpful and I am thankful to all of you for that. I am just trying to understand minute differences in different questions and interested in the way to write outcomes one by one. That is why I posted a small and similar question. Convention for writing outcomes is still not very clear to me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson consider 3 shirts and 2 pants. If I pair up shirts and pants then one outcome is-> {(S1,P1),(S1,P2),(S2,P1),(S2,P2),(S3,P1),(S3,P2)}= 6 outcomes But If I take question differently like If in above, I consider that each shirt can be paired in 2 ways then there are 2³ ways { not aware of correct convention for such outcomes but smhow write using analogy from tossing coins }  now Replace shirts by coins and pants by H or T in that case outcomes are written differently like {(h,h,h),(h,h,t),(h,t,h),(t,h,h)....}=8 outcomes. If I write {(c1,h),(c1,t),(C2,h),(C2,t),(C3,h)(C3,t)}=6 outcm

Comment: The point, Level, is when you post two questions that are so close to each other, you must link each to the other. You must put your cards on the table, so people know what you do, or don't, understand.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought better to ask a similar question and then analyse the answers to grasp more. You can see I still yield different answers. E.g. in case of tossing 3 coins why 6 outcomes mentioned in above comment are incorrect. If I write outcomes like that what do they show so that they are incorrect? My confusion arises from basic concept as it is taught that if n(A)=m1 and n(B)=m2 then n(A×B)= m1.m2. then books show that 3 pants×2shirts= 6 ways to pair. Similarly why not 3coins×2h/t =6 outcomes?

Comment: You are not engaging with the point I made.

Comment: It did not come in my mind to share link here. I thought this question is over and I should ask new question. If you can provide answers to both( asked in above comments and in the other post) that will be helpful in understanding basics.

Comment: I hope that next time it will come to your mind to share links.

Answer (score 2):

I think your part A is wrong , so i need to write this answer.

**PART A-)**

This question is a type of flags into poles where the order of flags relevant.As you know , the order of rings msut be different in a finger , because one of them will be at bottom , the others are upper. For example , if we have $3$ rings  ,then we can insert them into a finger in $3!$ ways.

Now , we should handle that how many rings will be inserted by each fingers.For this , we will use stars and bars method. According to the method , we can distribute $3$ identical objects into $2$ distinct boxes (i.e fingers) by $$\binom{3+2-1}{3}=4$$ For example ,$*|**$ is one of the possible arrangement where stars represent the palces for rings .Moreover the left of the bar can be thought as the first finger and the right of the bar can be thought as the second finger. Now , lets place our $3$ distinct rings into the possible places which denoted by "stars".

We can place them $3!$ ways. Then , the answer is $$3!\binom{3+2-1}{3}=24$$

Comment: The problem seems similar to 1- putting 3 balls labled as b1, b2, b3 into two boxes B1 and B2.  2- two boxes B1 and B2 to put in 3 balls b1, b2 , b3. The more I dig the more it gets confusing.

Comment: In first case each ball has 2 ways therefore total 2³ ways (by multiplication principle). And in second case each boxes can contain 3 balls therefore 3² ways. I don't know if any of the logics here is correct or not. I was interested in finding pairs from the product manually.

Comment: @Level1 First of all , your part B is meaningless , because lets think a ring $1$ , so in your calculation $3^2$ , it counts the case that both finger takes ring $1$ at the same time. Do you think that it is possible ? Secondly , this question is different from classical balls and bins problems ,because when we wear the ring , they have to ordered in some situation from above to bottom

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. What does the up arrow above the flag means in the comment section? Is that an upvote?

Comment: In part B if I replace the ring by rubber band then will there be 3² ways?

Comment: @Level1 For the second question , it may be , but think it like post cards into post boxes. A post card cannot be in two distinct post boxes at the same time

Comment: Thank you again. I am asking about the triangle above the flag in the comment section. You can see it on the left side of this comment.

Comment: @Level1 not in comment , it is left hand side of my answer.

Comment: @Level1 you are welcome :))